# Postfix error "lost connection after RCPT' - email has over 100 + recipients

Tags: postfix

I have a Postfix server that is having issues receiving a distribution email from a customer mail server that has over 100+ recipients.  I have increased debug information using debug_peer_level and debug_peer_list.

What I have found is that after the Postfix server receives 99-102 "RCPT TO:" SMTP commands, it closes the connection.

The logs don't really indicate exactly what Postfix is doing at that point and I have increased my debug_peer_level to 99 to make sure I'm not missing any additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the recipient limit with

> smtp_destination_recipient_limit = 1024

Add this line to your main.cf and then, reload postfix.